# Delete Non-existing records From Table in a Stored Procedure with Try Catch shows completed successfully

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch, sql-delete

Ok, I'm literally getting bald from pulling my hair now! Almost 10 hours spending on this but couldn't figure out. I'm trying write a T-SQL stored procedure to delete records from 2 tables that match the input data, and print a message if delete was successful and commit the transaction, and if no records found, rollback the transaction and handle errors using a Try Catch. I have written the code below, but the problem is that even if the data don't match the input, I still get the "Command(s) completed successfully." message! I appreciate your help to fix my mistake. So far my code looks like this:

```
Use Northwind
Go

Create Procedure uspDeleteOrder
@orderID int As 
Set nocount on    
If Exists (Select * from Orders Where OrderID = @orderID)
Begin Try   
    Begin Transaction   
        Delete From dbo.[Order Details]
        Where dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = @orderID    
        Delete From Orders
        Where OrderID = @orderID   
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    Print 'The article has been deleted!'
End Try
Begin Catch
    IF (@@trancount > 0)
    Begin           
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    End
 PRINT '*************Error Detail****************'
 PRINT 'Error Number  :' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR)
 PRINT 'Error Severity:' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR)
 PRINT 'Error State   :' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR)
 PRINT 'Error Line    :' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR)
 PRINT 'Error Message :' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
End Catch

Exec uspDeleteOrder 11077
```

UPDATE: Ok, I edited my code to this, I guess pretty much does the job, however I'm not sure if it's the correct way of doing it:

```
Create Procedure uspDeleteOrder
@orderID int As 
Set nocount on    
If Exists (Select * from Orders Where OrderID = @orderID)
Begin
    Begin Try   
        Begin Transaction   
            Delete From dbo.[Order Details]
            Where dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = @orderID    
            Delete From Orders
            Where OrderID = @orderID   
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        Print 'The Order has been deleted!'
        return
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        IF (@@trancount > 0)
        Begin           
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RAISERROR ('Error', 16,1); 
        End
        PRINT '*************Error Detail****************'
        PRINT 'Error Number  :' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error Severity:' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error State   :' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error Line    :' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error Message :' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    End Catch
End
Else 
Begin
    RAISERROR ('No Order ID', 16,1);
End
```

Any opinions?

Comment: Try adding a `return` at the end of the `try` block.

Comment: By the way, a DELETE with conditions will always succeed even if no matching records were found for deletion.

Comment: @FDavidov you mean the first Try block? how does it help? I added a return before end try but didn't make a difference

Comment: When you think in terms of sets, a set containing 0 rows is as valid a set as one containing one row or multiple rows. As such, the fact that the set of rows that were deleted contained no rows is *not* considered an error.

Comment: If the delete affects 0 rows why do you want it to be rolled back? There's no work to undo.

Comment: If the delete affects 0 rows, it needs to raise an error.

Comment: You can check the number of rows deleted using `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS Rows_Deleted;` (must be immediately after the delete statement) and then check the value of Rows_Deleted. If 0 no deletion took place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to RAISERROR from within the Catch Block.

At the moment you are catching the error and selecting out the error details but the stored procedure still returns success.

Add a Line

```
RAISERROR ('Err', 16,1);
```

to the catch block

Comment: Minor point, but MS recommend [throw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx), over raise error, for new developments.  [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

So if there where no orderdetails deleted you want to print this ?
You can do that like this example below.
It is easy to modify to throw an exception in stead of printing or whatever you require

Also why the return statement ?

```
Create Procedure uspDeleteOrder
@orderID int As 

Set nocount on    

declare @DeleteOrderDetailCount int

If Exists (Select * from Orders Where OrderID = @orderID)
Begin
    Begin Try   
        Begin Transaction   
            Delete From dbo.[Order Details]
            Where dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = @orderID    

            select @DeleteOrderDetailCount = @@ROWCOUNT

            Delete From Orders
            Where OrderID = @orderID   

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        if @DeleteOrderDetailCount = 0
        begin
            Print 'There where no orders details to delete'
        end

        Print 'The Order has been deleted!'

        -- why a return here ????
        -- return
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        IF (@@trancount > 0)
        Begin           
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RAISERROR ('Error', 16,1); 
        End
        PRINT '*************Error Detail****************'
        PRINT 'Error Number  :' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error Severity:' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error State   :' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error Line    :' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR)
        PRINT 'Error Message :' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    End Catch
End
Else 
Begin
    RAISERROR ('No Order ID', 16,1);
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing rows affected with @@RowCount

```
DECLARE @v1 INT
DELETE From dbo.[Order Details]
Where dbo.[Order Details].OrderID = @orderID    
SET @v1 = @@ROWCOUNT
```

It would allow you to implement some logic to capture unwanted scenarios.